# @JmsListener suddenly stopped consuming messages without any errors or exceptions

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have an application running on production which consumes a virtual topic on ActiveMQ like

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "Consumer.example-consumer.VirtualTopic.${spring.activemq.example.topic}")
public void consumeTopic(String message) {...}
```

Where in application.properties

```
spring.activemq.example.topic=example.topic
```

Also I have configured my Active MQ in Spring Boot like

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class AmazonMQConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
    public String brokerURL;
    
    @Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
    public String userName;
    
    @Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
    public String password;
    
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        factory.setBrokerURL(brokerURL);
        factory.setUserName(userName);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        return new JmsTemplate(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        return factory;
    }
}
```

But suddenly yesterday my `@JmsListener` stopped consuming the messages from the virtual topic and there were around 82000 pending messages in my consumer queue in 24 hours.

Kindly help me with the issue as I am clueless why this issue occurred and unable to recreate it.

Further below I am providing my dependencies pom.xml code and the sample thread dump which I took when I got to know about the issue.

pom.xml:-

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Exclude Spring Boot's Default Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thread Dump:-

```
    2020-12-16 15:02:17
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.265-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #723 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77a8007800 nid=0x33b6 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker" #55 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77a00bc000 nid=0x6571 waiting on condition [0x00007f7782ffd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000855ef0a8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"reactor-http-epoll-4" #54 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77b84fb000 nid=0x655c runnable [0x00007f778c5af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:347)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"reactor-http-epoll-3" #53 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77b84f9800 nid=0x655b runnable [0x00007f778c6b0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:347)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"reactor-http-epoll-2" #52 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77b84f7800 nid=0x655a runnable [0x00007f778c7b1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:347)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"reactor-http-epoll-1" #51 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77b84f6800 nid=0x6559 runnable [0x00007f778c8b2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:347)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"DestroyJavaVM" #50 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77dc04c800 nid=0x651e waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"ActiveMQ Transport: ssl://b-d15b4567-aw8b-4k80-8jd9-343hht45ab97-2.mq.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/172.158.11.158:61617" #44 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77a8009800 nid=0x6554 runnable [0x00007f778d2c6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990)
    - locked <0x00000000855731a0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:948)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    - locked <0x00000000855c6688> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.fill(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.fill(TcpTransport.java:634)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.read(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:59)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.read(TcpTransport.java:619)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1" #42 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77dd72c800 nid=0x6552 waiting on condition [0x00007f778d4c8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000008a8e04d0> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1680)
    at com.main.service.SingularConnectionService.sendDataToSingular(SingularConnectionService.java:38)
    at com.main.consumer.AmazonMQConsumer.consumeTopic(AmazonMQConsumer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer" #40 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7798038000 nid=0x6550 in Object.wait() [0x00007f778d6ca000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x000000008556c420> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"ActiveMQ Transport: ssl://b-d15b4567-aw8b-4k80-8jd9-343hht45ab97-2.mq.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/172.158.11.158:61617" #38 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7794571800 nid=0x654e runnable [0x00007f778d8cc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990)
    - locked <0x00000000855d9288> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:948)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    - locked <0x00000000855da5e8> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.fill(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.fill(TcpTransport.java:634)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.read(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:59)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.read(TcpTransport.java:619)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor ReadCheckTimer" #37 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7794210800 nid=0x654d in Object.wait() [0x00007f778d9cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000000855eebe0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1" #36 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77dd743000 nid=0x654c in Object.wait() [0x00007f778dcce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.activemq.FifoMessageDispatchChannel.dequeue(FifoMessageDispatchChannel.java:74)
    - locked <0x00000000855eac88> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dequeue(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:486)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:653)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:418)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:303)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"http-nio-8082-Acceptor" #34 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77dd827800 nid=0x654a runnable [0x00007f778ded0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:419)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:247)
    - locked <0x00000000853bcca0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:469)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hi Justin, yes it worked. Thank you so much for the help, apologies for the delay in response.

Comment: could you please advise what the issue was? I am also seeing a similar thread dump. The stacktrace shows the place where I use Spring Webclient to make a remote API call. Is your use case also similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single thread dump doesn't help much because it only provides a snapshot of what the application is doing. What you really need is a series of thread dumps so you can see what the threads are doing *over time*. However, since all you've provided is a single thread dump I'd say your problem is this thread:

```
"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1" #42 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f77dd72c800 nid=0x6552 waiting on condition [0x00007f778d4c8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000008a8e04d0> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1680)
    at com.main.service.SingularConnectionService.sendDataToSingular(SingularConnectionService.java:38)
    at com.main.consumer.AmazonMQConsumer.consumeTopic(AmazonMQConsumer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is the thread which is actually consuming the message from the topic. Notice that it is *blocked* in this method:

```
com.main.service.SingularConnectionService.sendDataToSingular()
```

It's not clear how long this blocking happens, but it's possible that this block never clears up and basically prevents your consumer from receiving any more messages. Since you're using `setConcurrency("1-1")` you only have one consumer so if it's blocked then no more messages will be consumed.

You should investigate what this method is doing and ensure you invoke any blocking operations with a timeout so threads can't be blocked indefinitely.