# Process pending messages faster in ActiveMQ using concurrent user

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a queue which is getting consumed by an Spring Boot application. As my Spring Boot application is waiting for response from a REST API its not able to process the incoming messages faster due to which the number of pending messages is increasing on my queue.

I have done some R&D and came out with the solution which is mentioned below. Kindly help me by reviewing the solution so that I can know whether I am on a right track.

My current ActiveMQ configuration:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    factory.setBrokerURL(brokerURL);
    factory.setUserName(userName);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    return factory;
}
```

My planning for solution:-

```java
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("1-50");
    factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(10);
    factory.setReceiveTimeout(5000L); // 5 seconds
    return factory;
    }
    
@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    factory.setBrokerURL(brokerURL);
    factory.setUserName(userName);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    
    ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy policy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
    policy.setQueuePrefetch(1);
    factory.setPrefetchPolicy(policy);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: The best way to know whether or not this will work is to actually test it. Have you actually tested it? If so, did it work? If not, why not?

Comment: Thank you so much Justin for the reply, I have to test it, but I am going slowly as this has to go to production where we can actually load test it. Will let you know the result once we deploy it.

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram it worked really well, I was able to consume messages at the rate of approx 3000 messages per second, from 579000 pending messages to 0, it took approx 5 min. Thank you so much for reviewing the code and providing your insights.

Comment: You probably know this already, but load testing in production is quite a bad idea. Generally speaking you should have an environment where you can generate production equivalent load to test and tune before deploying to production.

Comment: Yup I understand this, but we are very much limited with resources, we try to manage this by performing such tests in a safe time window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, more consumers (especially concurrent consumers) will process messages more quickly than fewer consumers so this looks good from that perspective.

Comment: Thank you for the review Justin, I also agree on that, also I am planning to make the rest call in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346682/jmslistener-suddenly-stopped-consuming-messages-without-any-errors-or-exception) asynchronous based on your input.